# Command to find SD card UUID on Linux

Tags: linux, hardware

What is the command to find SD card UUID on Linux ?

BTW: My SD card is not a USB device.

Answer (score 4):

I found this command :

`lsblk -o name,serial,uuid,partuuid,label,partlabel /dev/sdb`

Comment: the one helped straight away on my linux mint.

Comment: Very usefull, I finally got a match on my microSD from the terminal.

Comment: For people that wants to find out a block device by label: `lsblk -o name,serial,uuid,partuuid,label,partlabel $(blkid --label MY_MICROSD)`

Answer (score 3):

You don't say which distribution you have.

`usb-devices` returns serial number information (if available) for all usb devices (on Debian, root not required).

You could also try (as root, or via `sudo`),

`udevadm info -a -n /dev/sdb`

changing the device to the SD card reader device.  This requires your Linux distribution to support `udev`.

The pretty common `lshw` (again, run as root is best) might also return the information (untested here).

Comment: I've updated my question.

Comment: So do `udevadm` or `lshw` work?  Neither of those are specific to USB devices.

Comment: If my SD card serial is `ABCD-EF12`,

`$ sudo lshw | grep -i ABCD-EF12` does not return anything
and btw, my sd card has no FAT32 label :
`$ sudo mlabel -si /dev/mmcblk0p1
 Volume has no label`
and `$ sudo udevadm info -a -n /dev/mmcblk0 | grep -i ABCD-EF12` returns nothing either.
Do you have any other command ?

Comment: Sorry, I have found out that what I'm searching for is the UUID.
Updating the question right away...